# How to configure Azure Notification Hub with APNS token for push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I had a lot of trouble getting through this because much of the information out there was out of date. I figured I'd post my own Q and A.

Answer (score 3):

1) Login to developer.apple.com with your membership ID and go to Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles

2) Go to the keys section

3) Click add, give the key a memorable name and enable APNs

4) Pay attention to the Key ID (note it)

5) Download the .p8 file that gets created, open it in textedit (or some editor) and copy the key that's inside.  Mine had -----BeginRequest  ----EndRequest... I just ignored that and copied the key itself

6) You will also need your app id.  Usually goes com.company.ProductName

7) You will also need your team id.  You can get this from your Membership Details Page (go back to main account page and choose Membership, then look for TeamID)

8) Finally, go to Azure Notification Hubs and configure APNs.

9) Enter the key id that you noted from the key you generated

10) Enter the app id in App Name field (I know this seems weird but trust me).  Example  com.Company.Product

11) Enter the team id in the App Id field.  (Yes, this is a little strange)

12) Finally take the token you copied from the contents of .p8 file and paste that in token field.

13) Select whether its a Sandbox (debug) or Production and you are all set.

If it works without error you are ready to go.  If you get an error you probably didn't enter the information correctly for one of the steps.  Pay close attention to App Name and App Id because they are misleading.  Follow the above instructions closely.

Comment: Looks like they've updated the UI now (Bundle ID and Team ID) but this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

The OP has already figured it out, but in case someone's wondering in the future, there's an official blog post about it: [Token-based (HTTP/2) Authentication for APNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-http2-token-authentification) with screenshots and property name mapping.